# How to retrieve field names from temporary table (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, temp-tables

I'm using SQL Server 2008. Say I create a temporary table like this one:

```
create table #MyTempTable (col1 int,col2 varchar(10))
```

How can I retrieve the list of fields dynamically? I would like to see something like this:

```
Fields:
col1
col2
```

I was thinking of querying sys.columns but it doesn't seem to store any info about temporary tables. Any ideas?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
select * from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id =
object_id('tempdb..#mytemptable');
```

Comment: Good ans. Use `select name from tempdb.sys.tables` get all the temporary table names

Comment: Verified that this method doesn't return data from #temp tables created via a different connection. The alternatives using LIKE #temp% do.

Answer (score 32):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name LIKE '#MyTempTable%'
```

Comment: This answer is better. The table name is included as well as the datatype for the column. If your where clause contains a list of temp tables, then this is even more superior because you can differentiate which columns come from what temp table

Comment: @VISQL Actually, the accepted answer is better because it does not use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. You can easily get the datatypes by JOINing to `sys.types` and you can easily get the table names via `OBJECT_NAME( object_id , database_id )` or JOINing to `tempdb.sys.tables`. This is all that the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` Views do.

Comment: The problem with this is that if you are using 2 temp tables with similar names (e.g #TEMP1 and #TEMP12) then when using #TEMP1 as the table name you also get the columns for #TEMP12

Comment: Using '#MyTempTable[_][_][_]%' works better to ensure you don't get other tables whcih start with name of the table you are looking for

Comment: Downvoted as: Verified that the accepted answer doesn't return data from #temp tables created via a different connection. This method does. The accepted answer is much safer.

Answer (score 8):

To use information_schema and not collide with other sessions:

```
select * 
from tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name =
    object_name(
        object_id('tempdb..#test'),
        (select database_id from sys.databases where name = 'tempdb'))
```

Answer (score 7):

The temporary tables are defined in "tempdb", and the table names are "mangled".

This query should do the trick:

```
select c.*
from tempdb.sys.columns c
inner join tempdb.sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name like '#MyTempTable%'
```

Marc

Comment: I think this could cross scopes. If it's one time code, fine. If it's code that will have a real lifespan, problem.

Comment: Yep, bad solution - if multiple connections created temp tables with the same name (eg in a proc that gets called from an application), this will be wrong.

Comment: Downvoted as: Verified that the accepted answer doesn't return data from #temp tables created via a different connection. This method does. The accepted answer is much safer.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it by following way too ..

```
create table #test (a int, b char(1))

select * From #test

exec tempdb..sp_columns '#test'
```

Comment: provides everything needed to write the explicit `CREATE TABLE`: 
`exec tempdb..sp_columns '#test'`

Answer (score 1):

Anthony

try the below one. it will give ur expected output

```
select c.name as Fields from 
tempdb.sys.columns c
    inner join tempdb.sys.tables t
 ON c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name like '#MyTempTable%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME=OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID('#table'))
```