# Find the column names of Temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

I need to find the **column names** of **temp table**.

If it is a physical table then we can either use `sys.columns` or `Information_schema.columns` system views to find the column names.

Similarly is there a way to find the column names present in temp table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve field names from temporary table (SQL Server 2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756080/how-to-retrieve-field-names-from-temporary-table-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   tempdb.sys.columns
WHERE  object_id = Object_id('tempdb..#sometemptable');
```

Answer (score 9):

To get only columns name you can  use this query below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#temp');
```

To get columns name with data type you can use this query but you need to make sure sp_help runs in the same database where the table is located (tempdb).

```
EXEC tempdb.dbo.sp_help @objname = N'#temp';
```

you can achieve same result by  joining against tempdb.sys.columns like below:

```
SELECT [column] = c.name, 
       [type] = t.name, c.max_length, c.precision, c.scale, c.is_nullable 
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns AS c
    INNER JOIN tempdb.sys.types AS t
    ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
    AND t.system_type_id = t.user_type_id
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#temp');
```