# Get column names of temp table in Azure Synapse DW

Tags: azure-synapse

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535457/find-the-column-names-of-temp-table) offers the canonical way of doing this in SQL Server, but it doesn't work in Azure Synapse.

Because it is a temp table, I cannot look in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, and I can't query `tempdb` or `tempdb.columns` like one might normally.

I'd like a query that yields the column `stack` from `#test`

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #test
END;

CREATE TABLE #test
WITH (DISTRIBUTION=ROUND_ROBIN,HEAP)
AS (
SELECT 'overflow' as stack
);

SELECT * FROM #test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, sorry.

The only workable "solution" is to CTAS a row to a table outside tempdb, then inspect its columns from sys.columns or information_schema.