# I need to get the list of row names of a particular column name in a dynamic temp table in SQL. How would I construct a while loop which does this?

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I need to create a temp table with dynamic row names, and then get the row names in a list of strings, which I  use later in my procedure

Comment: You said row names, instead of column names, is this temp table supposed to be pivoted?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756080/how-to-retrieve-field-names-from-temporary-table-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have already created your dynamic temp

To get the fields in a temp

```
select * from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#Temp');
```