# Get list of columns in a temp table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am creating a temporary table on-the-fly using `Select * Into #temp from SomeChangingSource` in a stored procedure. I need to then list the resulting columns.

Handling this for a regular (permanent) table is as simple as:

```
select COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='TableName'
```

How do I handle this for a temporary table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve field names from temporary table (SQL Server 2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756080/how-to-retrieve-field-names-from-temporary-table-sql-server-2008)

Comment: The question was perfectly answered 7 years ago.

Comment: The comment is automatically generated when I voted to close as a dupe.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your were close.  Just needed to point it to Tempdb.Sys.Columns

```
 Select * From  Tempdb.Sys.Columns Where Object_ID = Object_ID('tempdb..#TempTable')
```