# List down the column names in a Temporary Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am a beginner to SQL Server Database. I have a basic question.

How to retrieve the column names of a `temporary table` in `SQL Server`? 
I have tried querying the `sys.objects`, but the table is not listing there.

Comment: The temporary table metadata will be stored in tempdb.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve field names from temporary table (SQL Server 2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756080/how-to-retrieve-field-names-from-temporary-table-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Obj.NAME
    ,Col.NAME
FROM tempdb.sys.objects Obj
INNER JOIN tempdb.sys.columns Col ON Obj.object_id = Col.object_id
WHERE Obj.NAME LIKE '#tmp%'
```

But please note that the local temporary table names will not be unique. We can have the same names from different sessions. So be careful with the query.

Comment: Thank you very much. Also thanks for sharing the information on different sessions as well. Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

Temp tables are stored in the `tempdb` database so you have to query the views from the `tempdb` database.  Something like this:

```
SELECT c.name
FROM tempdb.sys.objects o
INNER JOIN tempdb.sys.columns c ON c.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.name LIKE '#TempTableName%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get the temp table for just the current session.

```
SELECT c.name
FROM tempdb.sys.objects o
INNER JOIN tempdb.sys.columns c ON c.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.object_id = object_id('tempdb..#TempTableName)
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Not displaying any records.

Answer (score 1):

```
`SELECT STUFF( 
   `(SELECT ',' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(name,''))) 
      `FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
      `WHERE Object_ID = Object_ID(N'tempdb..#TEMP')
      `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') 
`AS comma_separated_list
```

Comment: Hello and welcome!
You should use code blocks in questions and answers https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks